# Retrieve sk_buff on Android with 802.11

Tags: android, network-programming, linux-kernel, kernel-module, kernel

I have quite a specific piece of code here and so far the internet has been of little help. I'm trying to write a piece of code that (for starters) should just be able to read out an 802.11 (wireless) packet and print information from the MAC header. I tried composing my code out of different tutorials, pieces of kernel information, ... The program that I'm trying to write is a loadable kernel module for android (although linux kernel is very similar). While I can currently receive sk_buff packets, it seems to me these are totally wrong. This is the code I have so far:

```
/* 
 *  AUTHOR:     MATHIEU DEVOS
 *  
 */
/* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

/* KModule specific */
#include <linux/skbuff.h> /* ptype_function and others */
#include <linux/netdevice.h> /* used to print list of devices */
#include <linux/nl80211.h> /* used for iftypes types */
#include <net/cfg80211.h> /* used to handle ieee80211_ptr that point to wireless_dev*/
#include <linux/if_ether.h> /* used to specifiy which ethernet packages driver gets, not for header! */
#include <linux/netfilter.h> /* used to determine what to do with the packets */
#include <linux/string.h> /* used for memcmp */
#include <linux/ieee80211.h> /* used for 802.11 header and constants */
#include <net/mac80211.h> /* used for handling skb and getting hw */

/* used to show defines, currently unused, remove later on */
#define STR(x) #x
#define SHOW_DEFINE(x) printk(KERN_CRIT "%s = %s\n", #x, STR(x));


/* defines for modinfo */
#define DRIVER_AUTHOR "Mathieu Devos <mathieu.devos@ugent.be>"
#define DRIVER_DESC "Basic ethernet test"

/* Actual coding start */

/* initialisation of variables and functions */

    /* variables */
struct net_device *dev;
struct ieee80211_hw *hw;
static int foundWLAN = 0;
static struct packet_type ptype;

    /* functions */
static void print_mac_hdr(struct ieee80211_hdr *e_hdr);
static int dev_is_wireless(struct net_device *dev);
static void throw_hook(struct net_device *dev);
static int ptype_function(struct sk_buff *skb, struct net_device *dev, struct packet_type *ptype, struct net_device *dev2);


/*start of functions*/

static void print_HWinfo(void){
    printk(KERN_CRIT "Network device: %s\n",dev->name);
    printk(KERN_CRIT "Network address: %pM\n",dev->dev_addr);
}

static int dev_is_wireless(struct net_device *dev){
    #ifdef CONFIG_WIRELESS_EXT
        if(dev->wireless_handlers && dev->operstate!=5){
            return 1;
        }
    #endif
    if(dev->ieee80211_ptr && dev->operstate!=5){
        return 1;
    }


    return 0; /* default false */
}

static int ptype_function(struct sk_buff *skb, struct net_device *dev1, struct packet_type *ptype, struct net_device *dev2){


    struct ieee80211_hdr *whdr = NULL;
    whdr = (struct ieee80211_hdr *)skb->mac_header;




    printk(KERN_CRIT "head: %pF",skb->head);
    printk(KERN_CRIT "mac_header: %pF",skb->mac_header);
    printk(KERN_CRIT "network_header: %pF",skb->network_header);
    printk(KERN_CRIT "transport_header: %pF",skb->transport_header);

    printk(KERN_CRIT "len: %u",skb->len);
    printk(KERN_CRIT "data_len: %u",skb->data_len);
    printk(KERN_CRIT "mac_len: %u",skb->mac_len);
    printk(KERN_CRIT "hdr_len: %u",skb->hdr_len);

    printk(KERN_CRIT "SKBUFF size: %u", sizeof(*skb));


    /*
    print_mac_hdr(whdr); */

    /* sizeof(*whdr)) = 30 bytes */
    /* sizeof(*ehdr)) = 14 bytes */

    if(memcmp(whdr->addr1,dev1->dev_addr,dev1->addr_len)==0){
        print_mac_hdr(whdr);
    }


    dev_kfree_skb(skb);
    return NF_DROP; /* NF_DROP Basically, print the info of the all the packets flying around, then drop it */
}

static void print_mac_hdr(struct ieee80211_hdr *whdr){

    printk(KERN_CRIT "DA ADDR: %pM\n",whdr->addr1);
    printk(KERN_CRIT "BSSID ADDR2: %pM\n",whdr->addr2);
    printk(KERN_CRIT "SA ADDR3: %pM\n",whdr->addr3);
    printk(KERN_CRIT "UNUSED ADDR4: %pM\n",whdr->addr4);
    /*printk(KERN_CRIT "PROTOCOL: 0x%04x\n",ntohs(ehdr->h_proto));*/
}

static void throw_hook(struct net_device *dev){
    ptype.type = htons(ETH_P_ALL); /* listen to all ethernet packets! This should still work, even for 802.11, change later */
    ptype.func = &ptype_function;
    ptype.dev = dev;
    dev_add_pack(&ptype);
    printk(KERN_CRIT "Done setting up packet type");

}

static void delete_hook(struct net_device *dev){
    dev_remove_pack(&ptype);
    synchronize_net();
}

/* Handle init and exit of module */

static int __init init_mymodule(void){
    printk(KERN_CRIT "Started kernel module!\n");

    dev = first_net_device(&init_net);
    while(dev && !foundWLAN){
        foundWLAN = dev_is_wireless(dev);
        if(!foundWLAN){
            dev = next_net_device(dev);
        }
    }

    if(dev && dev->ieee80211_ptr->iftype==NL80211_IFTYPE_STATION){
        print_HWinfo();

        /*
        hw = wiphy_to_ieee80211_hw(dev->ieee80211_ptr->wiphy);
        if(!hw){
            printk(KERN_CRIT "Could not assign HW!");
        }else{
            printk(KERN_CRIT "Assigned hw!");
        }
        */

        throw_hook(dev);
    }

    return 0;

}

static void __exit exit_mymodule(void){

    delete_hook(dev);

    printk(KERN_CRIT "Finished kernel module, exiting \n");
}

module_init(init_mymodule);
module_exit(exit_mymodule);

/*
 *   Extra info for modinfo
 */

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

MODULE_AUTHOR(DRIVER_AUTHOR);
MODULE_DESCRIPTION(DRIVER_DESC);
```

Current items that I'm aware of:

1. when checking wifi devices I receive both p2p0 and wlan0, since I want to write generic code I would prefer not to select the "correct" device just based on the name. Hence why I'm selecting it based on the DORMANT (operstate) state.
2. Currently I'm unaware if I have to call for hardware information (wiphy_to_ieee80211_hw), but when trying to run said function my __init no longer returns 0 (thus it's getting an error code) and I can't even launch my module.
3. When trying to use skb->data my kernel crashes and also trying to read out the data pointer (*data) causes a crash.
4. As you can see below in the sample output that I'm currently receiving both mac_len, data_len are totally wrong. Mac_len should be 30 (bytes for 802.11 header) and data_len, well, shouldn't be 0 all the time.

A sample of the current output:

```
<2>[19476.400718] c0 head: 0xe2e4f440
<2>[19476.400766] c0 mac_header: 0xe2e4f48e
<2>[19476.400818] c0 network_header: 0xe2e4f432
<2>[19476.400873] c0 transport_header: 0xe2e4f440
<2>[19476.400929] c0 len: 78
<2>[19476.400964] c0 data_len: 0
<2>[19476.401003] c0 mac_len: 14
<2>[19476.401041] c0 hdr_len: 0
<2>[19476.401079] c0 SKBUFF size: 184
<2>[19476.401307] c0 head: 0xe2e4f440
<2>[19476.401362] c0 mac_header: 0xe2e4f4dc
<2>[19476.401423] c0 network_header: 0xe2e4f432
<2>[19476.401485] c0 transport_header: 0xe2e4f440
<2>[19476.401541] c0 len: 156
<2>[19476.401577] c0 data_len: 0
<2>[19476.401615] c0 mac_len: 14
<2>[19476.401656] c0 hdr_len: 0
<2>[19476.401701] c0 SKBUFF size: 184
```

Hope to receive some positive insight on these issues since I'm new to posting on this website, but have been using it for quite a while to help me with my programming issues.

First quick edit before I save all progress and try to look for more tomorrow:

added:

```
extern struct ieee80211_hw *wiphy_to_ieee80211_hw(struct wiphy *wiphy);
```

to the functions initialisation (when trying to do same but with wiphy_to_ieee80211_hw instead of *wiphy_to_ieee80211_hw I seem to get a whole bunch of errors). With the pointer function (*wiphy_to_ieee80211_hw) I only get that it's undefined.
So it's still undefined this functions, which is rather annoying to me. I changed my makefile to add: KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS=../kernel/net/mac80211 (this is where the export_symbol is at: ../kernel/net/mac80211/util.c)
Total makefile:

```
obj-m += ethernet_test.o

all:
  make -C ../kernel M=$(PWD) KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS=../kernel/net/mac80211 modules
clean:
  make -C ../kernel M=$(PWD) clean
```

Also tried to load in ieee80211_hw in __init part again with:

```
struct ieee80211_hw *hw = wiphy_to_ieee80211_hw(dev->ieee802_ptr->wiphy);
```

But due to this still being undefined it's not resulting in ieee80211_hw and thus it crashes my module (won't even load) :(.